# returning false not stopping the submission of form

Tags: javascript

My purpose: If the user field and password field are blank, I want to stop form submitting.
This is my Code that I am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function doit() {

            var usr = document.getElementById('ur').value;
            var psw = document.getElementById('pw').value;

            if ((usr.trim() == '') && (psw.trim() == '')) {
                alert("cannot Submit form");
                return false;
            }

        }
    </script>

</head>


<body>

    <form action="post.php" method="post" onsubmit="doit()">
        User:
        <input type="text" id="ur" name="user">
        <br>
        <br> Pass:
        <input type="password" id="pw" name="pass">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

I am learning JavaScript. Will be helpful if you correct the code with a little explanation why it is not working.

Comment: add `required` attribute to your inputs, in the modern browsers the effect will be the same. And in your function I would use OR operator, not AND - both values should not be empty.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`return false` is working fine, the way you are ***calling*** that function is wrong.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" onsubmit="doit()">
```

Just calls it, doesn't do anything with the return value

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" onsubmit="return doit()"> 
                                                ^
```

Will stop the form post on a false returned value.

Read this note on **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536972(v=vs.85).aspx)** although it is not IE specific

> You can override this event by returning false in the event handler. Use this capability to validate data on the client side to prevent invalid data from being submitted to the server. **If the event handler is called by the onsubmit attribute of the form object, the code must explicitly request the return value using the return function, and the event handler must provide an explicit return value for each possible code path in the event handler function**.

Now onto another important point.

Your `if` condition will only stop form submission when both the fields are blank, whereas it should do that even if any one of those two fields is blank. That `&&` (AND) should be an `||` (OR), and at the end of your functions if nothing returned false, `return true` then.

Comment: Regarding *> the event handler must provide an explicit return value for each possible code path in the event handler function* -- don't forget to add a `return true;` (or something else) at the end of `doit()`!

Comment: @Bob - adding `return true` at the end isn't necessary, although it would be nice because it avoids getting a "not all paths return a value" warning in some editors and lint checkers. But the code will work correctly without it. If you fall out of the end of the function without a `return`, the function returns `undefined`, which is not the same value as `false`. Consider the common case of an event handler that never returns `true` or `false` or any value at all - such a function would allow the form to be submitted. You have to explicitly `return false` to prevent submission.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Taking the quoted section literally, if the handler *must* provide an *explicit* return value then it would not be correct to rely on the implicit `undefined`. In practice, what you say will work on all current browsers to the best of my knowledge and might even be more correct according to HTML/ECMAScript specs (I don't have time to check), but if we were to take the MSDN article at its word then the explicit return value is *required*. (Though, this being MSDN and IE-focused it might just be covering VBS for all I know...)

Comment: @Bob - That's just sloppy wording in the MSDN article. The last part, "...and the event handler must provide an explicit return value for each possible code path in the event handler function", is just plain wrong. Every return from every function always provides an explicit return value whether you use a `return` statement or not. If you fall off the end of a function without a `return`, then the function returns `undefined`. If the MSDN article were correct, you could meet its requirement with an explicit `return undefined` at the end of the function, but that's the same as no `return`.

Answer (score 14):

`onsubmit` event accepts boolean values, since you are not returning anything so it assumes true by default. You need to add return in this event explicitly like mentioned below:

change

```
onsubmit="doit()">
```

to

```
onsubmit="return doit()">
```

Answer (score 7):

Using addEventListener on submit with preventDefault()

```js
document.form1.addEventListener( "submit", function(event) {

    var user = this.querySelector("input[name=user]").value; // this = object of form1
    var pass = this.querySelector("input[name=pass]").value;

    if ( (user.trim() == "") || (pass.trim() == "") ) {
        alert("cannot Submit form");
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        alert("submit");
    }

} );
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" >
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" /><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /><br><hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/antelove/pen/zYYvZZY)

[repl.it](https://repl.it/@antelove19/javascript-submit-preventdefault)