# Form is submitting even after validation function returning false

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

This question is asked many times. And I reviewed most of them and the problem in all the cases was.

1. They were not writing `return` before function call `onSubmit` form.
2. They were using `onClick` instead of `onSubmit`.
3. They were returning false inside `if` statement, so if the `if` is not true so function returning true and form is submitting.

**But my case different from all the above cases.**

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form-box" name="booksUpload" action="action_page.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    /*Various input fields.*/    
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
        <script>
            function validateForm(){

                /*Validating phone numner*/
                var phone = document.forms["booksUpload"]["phone-number"].value;
                var phErr = document.getElementById("phError");

                if(phone.toString().length != 10){
                    phErr.innerHTML = "Enter a valid mobile number (10 digits)";
                }
                else{
                    phErr.innerHTML = "";
                }

                /*Validating Status*/
                var status = document.forms["booksUpload"]["status"];
                var checked = false;
                var statusErr = document.getElementById("statusError");

                for(var i = 0; i < status.length; i++){
                    if(status[i].checked){
                        checked = true;
                        break;  
                    }
                }

                if(checked == false){
                    statusErr.innerHTML = "Select one option \"Old or New\"";
                }

                else{
                    statusErr.innerHTML = "";
                }

                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify, still unclear what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I don't want my form to submit, so I return false from validatonForm() method. Still the form is submitting.

Comment: Check my answer bellow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your submit function is correct ! Just try by writing full html for your function requirement element or id !!!

```
<form id="form-box" name="booksUpload" action="action_page.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" name="phone-number">
    <select name="status"></select>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
<p id="phError"></p>
<p id="statusError"></p>
```

> function execution is not reaching till return statement, as something wrong within other statements before return. When everything works good in function so return` statement will execute and return false and form will not submit

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your answer, please make it more clear.

Comment: You have `document.forms["booksUpload"]["phone-number"].value;` in function so If `form` doesn't have name like `phone-number` it will throw error and your the whole function will not working and return nothing !!

Comment: On submitting the form. `innerHtml` of the `phErr` element is changing when I input 6-7 digit number and then the page goes to `action_page.php`. So I think t is not wrong with `phone-number` element.  I think it is wrong with the status validation. btw I think my problem is found. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 6):

You should prevent form submission before calling your function

```
onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validateForm();"
```

Comment: Form submission is done after the function calling. It is assured by executing the `innerHtml` I used in the funtion.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had tried using camelcase `onSubmit` and using the `return` keyword in front of my function call, but adding `event.preventDefault();` ahead of the function call at last prevented Firefox v82 from submitting a form when the function returned false. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

In JQuery `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring, `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and return false will do both.

In non JQuery `return false` does not stop the event from bubbling up

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using HTML5 forms with [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation). All modern browsers support it and even for the outdated there are good polyfills.

Here 's a small example.

```
<form id="constraint-form" method="post" action="">
    <label for="phone-number">phone number</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" value="" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>

    <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="submit">
</form>
```

Just have a try for yourself. This small example executes without Javascript and validates the phone number for 10 digits because of its required attribute.

To push even more, you can use Javascript, to display error messages.

```
<input type="tel" name="phone-number" id="phone-number" value="" pattern="[0-9]{10}" data-valuemissing="Your phone number is required" data-patternmismatch="Please enter digits only. Your phone number needs 10 digits." required>

var form = document.querySelector('#constraint-form');
form.addEventListener('invalid', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var element = event.target,
        message = element.validationMessage;

    if (element.validity.valueMissing === true && element.dataset.valuemissing !== undefined) {
        message = element.dataset.valuemissing;
    }

    if (element.validity.patternMismatch === true && element.dataset.patternmismatch !== undefined) {
        message = element.dataset.patternmismatch;
    }
}, true);

element.setCustomValidity(message);
alert(message);
```

This is a small untested example. The form tag gets an invalid event listener and triggers if there 's an invalid form element within this form when submitting it. In this example the phone number input element is required and got its own data attributes as an example how to bind individual error messages to an element. When the element is empty or it doesnt match the pattern, one of the error messages will be alerted.

As long there is an invalid form element one cant submit the form. The magic of constraint validation! ;)

Comment: That;s good and helpful, but still I don't understand what's wrong with my codes?

Comment: Forget the `onsubmit` attribute in your form code. Just add an event listener to the form like `form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ... // if form is valid => form.submit(); });`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use **return** inside **onsubmit**.

```
<form id="form-box" name="booksUpload" action="action_page.php" onSubmit="validateForm()">
    /*Various input fields.*/    
</form>
```

Comment: Still not working. And I think using `onSubmit="return validationForm()"` is the right way not `onSubmit="validateForm()"`

I read it [there](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29816191/5132337).

Answer (score 0):

I have been with the same problem but for my case. I was previously using `onsubmit` but changed to camel case `onSubmit` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not accept the answer that suggested you use the `event.preventDefault()` before calling the validation function I want to suggest that you call the preventDefault in you validation function using

```
<form id="form-box" name="booksUpload" action="action_page.php" onSubmit="return validateForm(event)">
    /*Various input fields.*/    
</form>
```

and in your javascript use

```
<script>
    function validateForm(e){
        ...............
        //call this where ever you want to prevent submission
        e.preventDefault();
        .........
    }

</script>
```