# preventing form submission if entered values are not correct in registration field in php

Tags: php, function, registration

using the following sample code in my registration form I've specified if the entered value doesn't meet these requirements, user gets an error message.

```
if (preg_match('some conditions here',$value)) {
                $return = $register_msg['some_error_msg'];
```

}

but above doesn't prevent registration request submission and user can click register button and registration takes place with false values which user entered!
so i need a function that as far as all fields are not correct,submission not take place

Comment: Could you share the form code where you have the form field and registration button? Also, could you share the complete code which handles submission? We don't know what $value carries and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent submission by returning false to onSubmit of the form using your js function. Check this thread [returning false not stopping the submission of form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816168/returning-false-not-stopping-the-submission-of-form).

Comment: my website is built via wordpress and registration form is made up via indeed membership pro plugin. 
i looked up this path in my host : wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership-pro/assets/js  and there are multiple js files such as "functions.js"  and  "jquery.form.js" but the problem is i don't know which one of these files to edit and what exact code to add and where to add within the js file.  more explanation would be appreciated