# Is this a valid if statement?

Tags: javascript

I have created function to catch a negative number, 0 or non-numerical value. For some reason it only catches the non-numerical value. I have copied the HTML and JS code below:

```js
function validate() {
  var num = document.myform.num.value;
  if (isNaN(num) || num == 0 || num < 0) {
    document.getElementById("principal").innerHTML = "Enter Numeric value only";
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onsubmit="validate()">
  Amount
  <input type="number" name="num" id="principal">
  <span id="principal"></span><br/>
</form>
```

I have tested it several times, I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: Be specific about what is not working here?

Comment: cause `"-" < 0`

Comment: I explained it is only catching the non-numerical value

Comment: Sorry what does this mean?  "-" < 0

Comment: You have to convert the string to a number, use `var num = Number(document.myform.num.value);`

Comment: What is the issue? For what specific input value it doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: You're not returning the return value of the `validate()` function call, so your form is being submitted. Other than that, it should work fine. (Even without explicitly converting the value to a number)

Comment: I have converted the string to number it still does not catch the second two clauses.

Comment: @nickzoum `isNaN`, `== 0` and `< 0` works with numbers in string form as well (most of the time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [returning false not stopping the submission of form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816168/returning-false-not-stopping-the-submission-of-form)

Comment: I have tried returning to validate it still does not catch it

Comment: You also have multiple elements with `id` `principal`. That's not allowed. [It works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/r48mbnuy/) when you only have it on the `<span>`.  (It also works fine if you don't, but it wont show the error message.)

Comment: I have removed the second ID and it still does not work

Comment: @IK1987 I added a link in my previous comment to a Fiddle that _does_ work (having fixed those issues).

Comment: Try with "number.isNaN()"

Comment: And try reorganize the statement. Put the num <=0 before and the number.isNaN after

Comment: Part of the problem resolved by removing the HMTL type of number. However, How do I refocus after an alert back to the input box?

Answer (score 0):

Using html 5 you can set a min attribute on the input element. This would cover your other two conditions of greater than 0. If you removed your function you could use the standard HTML 5 to detect that this isn't a number.

```
min="1"
```

Full code:

```html
<form name="myform">
  Amount
  <input type="number" name="num" id="principal" min="1">
  <span id="principal"></span><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: I need the conditions to create a message indicating they are specific to the problem, preferably an alert

Comment: It does display a tooltip message similar to what yours was doing when pressing enter.

Comment: I have found part of the problem, the HTML was typed as number. so I removed that it seems to catch the 3 statements. But I am now struggling to figure our how to return the focus back to the input box